# stack concept with array of object in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

class staticdemo
{
  static int rollno;
  string name;
 public:
  staticdemo()
  {
    cout<<"NAME: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    rollno++;
  }
  int getname()
  {
    cout<<name;
    return 0;
  }
  static int getvalu()
  {
    return rollno;
  }

};
int staticdemo::rollno=10;

int main()
{
  int i,n;
  cout<<"enter the number of studentd:";
  cin>>n;
  staticdemo s[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"name:"<<s[i].getname();
    cout<<"\nroll no: "<<s[i].getvalu();
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I learning C++, i have a doubt in stack with array of object concept,
in my above program i get the names from user and rollno incremented through stack 
while i retrieving list **back it will give finally updated stack value, how to get the fully updated rollno values,**  (how to display the unique rollno for every names),
pls post your valuable solution

Comment: I think you'll need to clarify the question : what do you want to do exactly ? Also, unrelated, `<iostream.h>` is non standard

Comment: `staticdemo s[n];` isn't doing you any portability favors either.

Comment: Great example of unquestionable question.

Comment: Using an `int` rather than a [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for the size of an array also isn't ideal.

Comment: First of all you should read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then you should know that having the input being made in the constructor not something you should have, think about what would happen if a temporary object of your class needed to be constructed? Then that would ask for input too. Instead ask for input in a loop in the main program, then create the object with a custom constructor that takes the name as an argument.

Comment: Oh and by the way, there's nothing about stacks in your question, except the mention in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want the `rollno` variable to be unique for each instance of the `staticdemo` class? Well then you can't have the member as `static`, because `static` members are shared among *all* instances of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I think I roughly understand your question, although it seems a bit hard to get what you need.

What you have done is partially right, you use a static member variable "rollno" to record the count, however, if you really want what you need, you will need another non-static variable to record the index, e.g:

```
class staticdemo {
    static int rollnoGlobal; // this will record the global count, used by everybody
    int myRollno; //Non-static, this will record the rollno index for this particular object
    string name;
 public:
    staticdemo() {
        cout<<"NAME: ";
        getline(cin,name);
        myRollno = rollnoGlobal; // This is the step for each individual to remember its index
        rollnoGlobal++;
    }
    int getname() {
        cout<<name;
        return 0;
    }
    static int getGlobalRollnoValue() {//return the global count;
        return rollnoGlobal;
    }
    int getMyRollno() { // return the index or you call it rollno for this particular object
        return myRollno;
    }
};
int staticdemo::rollnoGlobal=10;

int main() {
  int i,n;
  cout<<"enter the number of studentd:";
  cin>>n;
  staticdemo s[n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"name:"<<s[i].getname();
    cout<<"\nroll no: "<<s[i].getMyrollno();
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Again if I was correct, the problem you faced is more like a understanding of static member variable and methods in C++ classes.  This example you need two things:

1. A unique index for each variable, this is done by your original rollno static member.
2. Each staticdemo object must store its unique index.  And this is the step you missed.  After the global count increased, it increased for everybody because it is static. If you need to store it for each individual, you need another non-static member.

Side notes:

STACK is a very specific programming concept as pointed out by others, you question obviously does not need stack. You can try google what is a stack in programming.